# Meaning difference between using "is" and "has been"

Tags: perfect-constructions

What is meaning difference in the below sentences?

> Once your ID card number **has been** noted, there’s no way of escaping the fine.

and

> Once your ID card number **is** noted, there’s no way of escaping the fine.

Answer (score 2):

Either can be used, but it depends on context.

The first would be used in describing the process of being caught speeding. "If a policeman has pulled you over for speeding, once your ID card number has been noted, etc." In this case, the situation is described as having occurred at some time in the past, so the "has been noted" is the proper tense.

The second would be used as part of a narrative. "Imagine you're driving down the highway, not paying attention to the speedometer. A police officer pulls you over and issues you a ticket, and takes your ID card back to his cruiser. Once your ID card number is noted, there's no way of escaping the fine." Here, the situation is described in present (what you might call hypothetical or imaginary) tense, so "is noted" is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The auxiliary verb *is* is used in present continuous tense ie, to express the idea that something is happening now, at this very moment.

On the other hand, the form *has been* is used in the formation of present perfect continuous tense ie, to show that something started in the past and has continued up until now. .

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jenz. But in my examples which one is correct? because both sound me correct

Comment: I believe the first is correct, the second example (with is) just feels awkward and wrong.

Comment: The first one is better, because it is implied that the first clause occurs before the second one is possible. So technically the first clause using *has been* reaches into the past (and continuing up to now).

Answer (score 0):

its not an answer its just a doubt.
If it is something like an email for conformation can this be used like.
This is to conform that the pest control is scheduled for Sunday 
or
 the pest control has been scheduled for Sunday.